# Default menu bar in windows

Tags: java, windows, swt

I'm making an SWT application for both mac and windows. Just wondering how I can make the application use the default application menu bar in Windows. For mac, the command is `System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");`-what is the analogous command in windows?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that property is for Swing not SWT. On macOS the menu for a Shell always uses the standard macOS single menu bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: @greg-449 I had tried creating the shell menu without that command and it hadn't worked for me. Currently in the windows version of my application it is creating the menu below the application one and not over-riding it as I'd like it to do.

Comment: You need to show us an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Shell` `setMenuBar` method to set the main menu of a shell. This is all that is required on any platform:

```
Shell shell = .... 

Menu menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);

MenuItem menu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
menu.setText("File");

....
```